# How to get first 16 bytes of data from the base64 decoded string

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64

I want to read the first 16 bytes of data from the Base64Decode string. Here is my code. Please give any suggestions how to get first 16 bytes of data.

```
let base64Encodeded = "Hf8Qqpr1klv+Mjle4v0yfOXbQpiXwICyEDF4bYGt/ve7h9a1cEqd5z3QpvnPMLzRpDxSBEutaOdh8SN/Yi9OK2/oUxzJY6OoidPP6UFD42uDvBSJI98RKQxwceiUKZU8AzVLIMbrr01XvB9HSTkzGXfg2Ubw7zlts7mFLgi9IG6YZ1CWNHZ0rKzxrYAfz7e2vshAZOwDm6uaDbBT/00jSA==";
let base64decodeded=atob(base64Encodeded);// Getting °SÿM#H
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use node.js (as the tag suggests) you can use [Buffer.from](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_from_string_encoding) and then `slice` the output to get the first 16 bytes. The `encoding` parameter `base64` tells the function to treat the input string as base64 encoded and decode it into bytes:

```
let base64Encoded = "Hf8Qqpr1klv+Mjle4v0yfOXbQpiXwICyEDF4bYGt/ve7h9a1cEqd5z3QpvnPMLzRpDxSBEutaOdh8SN/Yi9OK2/oUxzJY6OoidPP6UFD42uDvBSJI98RKQxwceiUKZU8AzVLIMbrr01XvB9HSTkzGXfg2Ubw7zlts7mFLgi9IG6YZ1CWNHZ0rKzxrYAfz7e2vshAZOwDm6uaDbBT/00jSA==";
console.log(Buffer.from(base64Encoded, 'base64').slice(0,16));
```

the result is:

> <Buffer 1d ff 10 aa 9a f5 92 5b fe 32 39 5e e2 fd 32 7c>

Comment: thanks for your reply, We are not decoding the base64string right here? i need base64Decoded first16bytes

Comment: of course it's decoding the base64 encoded string. The result is the decoded content of your base64 string

Comment: compare the result with [this online tool](https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-hex), which decoded base64 to hex code: `1d ff 10 aa 9a f5 92 5b fe 32 39 5e e2 fd 32 7c`